Faulty proof that Axiom of Choice is not independent from the rest of ZFC
Here's my proof.
I'm reading Elements of Set Theory by Enderton 1 on 1 with a grad student at my University. I first remark on a particular passage in the book after it is pointed out that AC is not necessary for finite cases (since each choice can be pulled explicitly):

In particular, if we are choosing one thing, then we do not need the axiom of choice. (We mention this because people sometimes overreact when first hearing of the axiom of choice.) For example, assume that $A\neq\emptyset$. Then there exists some $y_0$ in $A$; we can use $y_0$ in further arguments (to show, e.g., that some singleton $\{y_0\}$ is a subset of $A$). This makes no use of the axiom of choice, even when phrased as "we can choose some fixed $y_0$ in $A$." For a second example, assume we are given a relation $R$. For any particular $x$ in $\text{dom }R$, there is a singleton $\{y_0\}$ included in $\{t|xRt\}$. We have not yet used the axiom of choice. What does require the axiom of choice is saying that for any $x$ in $\text{dom }R$ there is some $y_x$ for which $xRy_x$, and then putting all these $y_x$'s together into a set, e.g., $\{y_x|x\in\text{dom }R\}$. (Enderton, pp. 154-155)

However, the fact that we can construct $\{y_x|x\in\text{dom }R\}$ seems to come immediately from replacement which is cause for alarm. What I mean is that Enderton's statement of the Schema of replacement, about 25 pages later, states "For any formula $\phi(x,y)$ not containing the letter $B$, the following is an axiom: $\forall A[(\forall x\in A)\forall y_1\forall y_2(\phi(x,y_1)\text{ and }\phi(x,y_2)\to y_1=y_2)\implies\exists B\forall y(y\in B\leftrightarrow (\exists x\in A)\phi(x,y))]$". So to make it explicit, we can prove that Enderton's set $\{y_x|x\in\text{dom }R\}$ exists with the following set-up...
In my proofs I allow myself extensions by function names - note this is different from extension by definitions in that it does not require uniqueness. It is important to note that both of these allow us to add functions as symbols, not in the sense of ordered pairs. Enderton seems to use extension by function names constantly and especially when he refers to $y_x$. Here $y$ is essentially a function operating on $x$. Since $\text{dom }R$ is a well-defined set, we apply the schema of replacement to it where $y_x$ gives the mapping. It can be shown that $y_x$ satisfies the uniqueness precondition for replacement since $u=y_x$ and $v=y_x$ immediately imply $u=v$. Given the set Enderton speaks of, $\{y_x|x\in\text{dom }R\}$ (which we may call $B$), from separation on $A\times B$ (although again making use of $f$), we prove a set $F$ exists which is basically our choice function.
What in god's name is happening?

@spaceisdarkgreen according to the wiki articles I linked, to show that this function exists for a particular $A$ I only need to show that $\forall x\exists y(x\in A\to y\in x)$ because then I have a function $f$ such that $(\forall x\in A)f(x)\in x$. For $A$ where all $A$'s members are nonempty, this is trivial. This is just what I get directly from the article. I use the function symbol to obtain the range of the will-be choice function, then use separation to get the actual choice function. But then is not choice dependent on the other axioms?

@spaceisdarkgreen actually let me rephrase what I said. For every $x\in\text{dom }R$, there is $y$ such that $xRy$. So we make a function name $f$ with $xRf(x)$ for every $x\in\text{dom }R$. I only claim the function in question is a name, not a legal set of ordered pairs. Alternatively, $y_x$ picks from each ${t|xRt}$ by using $y_x=f(x)$. Same idea.

@spaceisdarkgreen That essentially answers my question. Out of slight further curiosity, is Axiom of Choice equivalent to the statement that separation and replacement hold in the extended language? If I just change replacement and separation to not require that do I just end up recreating ZFC?

I have the feeling that I've answered that before. The point, of course, is that there is no formula that defines the choice function (or transversal set, if you will).

@AsafKaragila I do give a formula in my 'proof'. SpaceIsDarkGreen commented that the flaw was that replacement and separation can't use my extended language with function names. I asked if allowing such functions to be used in the axiom of replacement is strictly equivalent to the axiom of choice
